# Source attachment does not contain the source file Collections.class?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

The following code i m using for my android application.while debugging in fourth line it is stopping and the below message is coming Source attachment does not contain the source file Collections.class.Please give me a soultion for this

```
String userName = "ClientTeam";
String password = "hZhUmdqq";
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:TEMPDB;instance=SqlExpress";
String JdbcDeriver="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(JdbcDeriver);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

Thanks,
kanna.

Comment: Could you add the complete error message please?

Comment: source not found The source attachment does not contain the source for the file Collections.class.you can change the source attachment by clicking change attached source below:

Comment: actually i want to connect sql server with java for that i m using.

Answer (score 0):

Is the right import in your code?

`import java.util.Collections;`